# Convert NSString date to NSDate or a specific string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Could you please help me with such converting
I have NSString date like @"2/8/2012 7:21:09 PM"
And I need to have such string in output:
"at 7:21 PM, february 8"
I've tried to use dateFormatter with different date patterns but it always return me null..I really don't understandd where I'm doing wrong :(

```
NSString *dateString = newsItem.Date;//Which is equal to @"2/8/2012 7:21:09 PM"
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];//I'm sure that this patternt is wrong but have no idea how to write the right one
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"date:%@", dateFromString);
```

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` is the right tool for this job. If it is always returning null, that means that the format string you're giving it doesn't match the actual date format. You'd have to show specifically what you're trying for someone to tell you what's wrong...

Comment: Post the code you have tried using dateFormatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use two different date formatters. First one to convert the string in to a date, the second one to output the date as a string with the specified format.

```
NSString* dateString = @"2/8/2012 7:21:09 PM";
NSDateFormatter* firstDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[firstDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate* date = [firstDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"Date = %@",date);

NSDateFormatter* secondDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[secondDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a, MMMM d"];
NSString* secondDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"at %@",[secondDateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

NSLog(@"%@",secondDateString);
```

The trick is the date format strings. They use a format called the unicode date format, the specification can be found [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: +1 Good point. It's "obvious" that you need 2 different formatters, unless you've never done this before, in which case it's not obvious at all...

Comment: hmm I still do not understand why two formatters, this is the frist. and the second: I've got the date(many thanks!!!) 2012-02-08 17:21:09 +0000 so why 17:21 if the time is 7 PM which means 19:21 isn't it?

Comment: Many thanks!! It works! You guys are awesome ^^ though, why it was 17:21 instead of 19:21 I still do not understand..anyway..it doesn't matter now just curious

Comment: So you may need to set the timezone property on NSDateFormatter